# One-liner probability problem

Tags: probability

Two people flip a coin $n$ times each. What is the probability that they both get the same number of heads?

If I let $k$ be the number of heads, I can get $$\frac{{n\choose k}^2}{2^{2n}}$$ which is correct so far: but I kind of don't understand why this is correct. Why doesn't $\frac{1}{2}$ show up anywhere? I would've expected $$(\frac{1}{2})^k (\frac{1}{2})^{n-k}$$ to appear somewhere. What I initially proposed was $\frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-k} {n\choose k}}{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2n}}$, why is this wrong?

Anyway, i could continue with the first equation to produce $$\frac{{2n\choose n}}{2^{2n}}$$ as the final probability. But I think there should be a logical argument that leads straight to the final answer in one line, given the equiprobability events. What could that be?

Edit: perhaps, the equiprobability explains my flawed second argument? I don't need to consider $\frac{1}{2}$ because both events are equally likely, so choosing is sufficient?

Comment: The reason you have ${n \choose k}^2$ as only the number of heads need to match between them and not the sequence. ${n \choose k}$ would mean it is the same $k$ tosses (same sequence) that are heads for both of them.

Comment: "*Why doesn't $\frac{1}{2}$ show up anywhere?*"  Note that $\dfrac{\binom{n}{k}^2}{2^{2n}}=\binom{n}{k}\cdot \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n\cdot \binom{n}{k}\cdot \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n$ and note that $x^k\cdot x^{n-k}=x^{k+(n-k)}=x^n$

Answer (score 0):

Because of the equiprobability we have:
$$
\left(\frac12\right)^k\left(\frac12\right)^{n-k}=\left(\frac12\right)^n
$$
so that $k$ magically disappears.

And you are right: one can directly obtain the final formula. Imagine $2n$ cells which you need to fill with heads and tails, the first half belonging to the first player and the second half - to the second one. We need to count all sequences with the equal number of heads in both halves. To do this choose arbitrary $n$ cells for heads and then invert heads and tails in the second half, which results in the equal numbers of heads in both halves. Since this procedure is obviously bijective, it gives us immediately the final expression.